# Independent numeric variable with two levels

Tags: mixed-model, continuous-data

I am studying whether two independent variables (frequency $freq$, and time $t$) influence a (continuous) output variable ($HR$). The independent variables are numeric. However, the experiment tests only two possible values for each of them. I am approaching the problem using Linear Mixed Effect models (LME), where the random effect is $SubjectID$, and the fixed effects are $freq$ and $t$.

How do I test if $freq$ "modulates" $HR$? In other words, how do I test if the two levels of $freq$ lead to different values of $HR$? It seems that even if the LME coefficient corresponding to $freq$ results statistically significant, that does not imply that $freq$ modulates $HR$; $HR$ may assume similar values across the levels of $freq$, and such values can still be accounted for by a linear coefficient in the model (of course the fit will not be perfect).

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the data-generating process?  Since you are using a mixed model, I assume you have a more than one observation or recorded value of frequency for any given $SubjectID$, is that correct?  Also, what kind of variable is $time$?  Is it a continuous variable (e.g. number of hours/minutes/seconds) or is it a categorical variable indicating the time point for data collection?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Each subject performs physical exercises, in particular leg presses. Frequency indicates the rate of the leg presses, and I test two values, time indicates the duration of the exercise (either 30s or 60s). Each subject goes through each combination of f and t only once.

Comment: Why did you feel like you needed to fit a mixed model?

Comment: Because the response variables may be non gaussian, and because there are missing values.

Comment: are $f$ and $t$ the only variables in the model?  If not, what other variables do you have?  Approximately what proportion is missing from these variables?  If they are a "large enough " proportions, do you have knowledge of the missingness-generating process?  For example, was it a skip pattern because of some characteristic of the subject (if the person was not healthy, we could not expect him to do the exercises, for example) or was it missing at random?

Comment: so is $freq$ continuous and $t$ binary, then?

Comment: I test two values of frequency too, 0.5 hz and 1 hz. Both t and f are used as numerical values in the model, however in practice there are only two values. The missingness is random due to malfunctioning of the instrumentation, and it can be around 3-5% of the data. There are two more variables : weight of the subject, and resistance of the leg presses (also two numerical values that depend on the weight, weight/3 and weight/6).

Comment: In your original question, you wanted to know if $f$ modulated (or modified, as I understood it) $HR$, was this correct or did you mean $time$ instead of HR?  The reason I'm asking so many questions is because I wanted to get clarity on what it is you are trying to answer in your research.  Is this the model you wanted to fit: $HR= freq + time + X$?  Were you interested in how $time$ modifies or modulates $freq$ at all?

Comment: No, I am sorry, I may have explained badly. There are four independent variables : frequency, time (ie duration of the exercise) , force and weight of the subject. In the original question I had simplified omitting Force and weight, because the question would not have changed in essence. Let's do this simplification again. There are two values of frequency, and there are two values of time, these are the fixed effects. There there is a random effect due to subject variability. The model, if we do not consider interaction terms, is therefore hr=freq+time+s, where s is a subject id.

Comment: The questions are whether the two levels of freq lead to (statistically) different values of her, and whether the two values of time lead to different values of hr.

Comment: Please note that a statistically significant value for the freq coefficient (for example) does not imply that the two levels of freq lead to statistically significantly different hr values.